# Redux-Form 7 Validation - Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux-form

so I'm trying to separate redux-form to stateless-component and container-component, but when I'm trying to do syncValidation, for some reason there is no validation called. what am I missing?

the error and warning in the renderField returns undefined.

and I'm planning to move the renderField function from the stateless component

container -

```
let EditMovie = (props) => {
const { updateMovie, editModal, editModalStateChange, invalid, initialValues, handleSubmit, pristine } = props;

return (   
    <MovieModal 
        modalTitle={initialValues.Title}
        initialValues= {initialValues} 
        invalid= {invalid} 
        validators= {Validators} 
        exit= {editModalStateChange} 
        isOpen= {editModal} 
        handleSubmit= {handleSubmit}
        onSubmit= {updateMovie}
        pristine={pristine}
    />
);
};

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {}
    if (!values.Title) {
        errors.username = 'Required'
    } 
    return errors
}

  const warn = values => {
    const warnings = {
        Title: 'bla bla'
    }

    return warnings
  }



const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    initialValues: state.movies.selectedMovie,
    editModal: state.movies.editModal,
});


EditMovie = reduxForm({ form: 'editMovie', validate, warn })(EditMovie);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { editModalStateChange, updateMovie } )(EditMovie);
```

stateless -

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
<div>
  <label>{label}</label>
  <div>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    {touched &&
      ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
        (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
  </div>
</div>
  )

const MovieModal = (props) => {

    const { pristine, handleSubmit, onSubmit, isOpen, exit, validators, invalid, modalTitle } = props;

    return (
        <Modal visible={isOpen} onClickBackdrop={() => exit()}>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field component={renderField} name="Title" label="Movie Title" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => exit()}>close</button>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" disabled={invalid || pristine}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide `validate` function in Field Component

Comment: this is for field-level-validation isn't it?

Comment: this can be done two ways for syncValidation providing the config parameters and field level validation. The way you did right now is correct but the order of HOCs are wrong. connect should be inside and reduxForm should be outside.

syncValidation
https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/syncvalidation/

Redux form and react-redux connect fucntion 
https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/

Comment: so for syncValidation it's just the HOC order replacement? I'm not supposed to pass validate function in the field component?

Comment: Correct. The thing you need to change is `export default reduxForm({...})(connect(....)(Component))`

Comment: still nothing, when the renderfield function is called it is getting error = undefined

Answer (score 0):

Well I Found the problem !

the issue was with the Bootstrap Modal module named - react-bootstrap4-modal

when i wrapped MovieModal in the Modal Class and not inside of it, everything worked fine

thanks for the help